# How to conditionally add a dependency to Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo

I have a Rust utility package containing different functionality separated via features (to provide only the specific functionality based on the need). The features have different dependencies which should be listed in `Cargo.toml` of the utility package. Is there a way to add dependencies in a way that it would be included only if the user of the package requires the specific feature (i.e. eliminate compilation of the dependencies if the feature is not used)?

Comment: You’re looking for [Cargo features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) probably

Comment: Do you mean "feature" instead of "future"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable conditional compilation of dependencies based on used features, there is a need to mark the dependency declaration as 'optional = true', then create a new feature combining all the used dependencies.
E.g. if we have a feature - f1 and only it in the package depends on 'rand' & 'anyhow', there is a need to mark dependencies as optional and include them as a part of the feature:

```toml
[dependencies]
anyhow = { version = "1.0", optional = true }
rand = { version = "0.8", optional = true }

[features]
f1 = [anyhow, rand]
```

Comment: doesnt it need to be something like this: f1 = ["dep:anyhow"]

Comment: By extension, is there a way to include a dependency if a feature is NOT enable?  My use case is that if I have a "uuid-customer-id" feature enabled, then I DO NOT need a dependency on rand.  When that feature is not enabled, then I need rand to generate a random character-based ID.

Comment: @ptdecker that’s addressed in the cargo book under “feature unification” https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-unification

Comment: The long and short of it is that you could split those two methods of ID generation into two features, specify a default, and use a compiler error macro for cases when neither are enabled